# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role while using Javers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, javers

I'm getting the error:
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.fleetx.persistence.model.Account.users, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

when I try to do a create operation on one of the entities I'm trying to audit using Javers. The following is the structure of my application:

AudityEntity.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class AuditEntity extends Base {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Account account;

    // other fields
}
```

Account.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table
public class Account extends Base {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<User> users;

    // other fields
}
```

AuditEntityRepository.java

```
@JaversSpringDataAuditable
public interface AuditEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<AuditEntityRepository, Long> {
    // crud operations
}
```

I don't want to change the fetch type of `private Account account;` or `private List<User> users;` to `FetchType.EAGER`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to change to `FetchType.EAGER` then wherever you are accessing `Account.getUsers()` needs to be in a transaction so the Hibernate Session isn't discarded.  The easiest way to do this is to add the `@Transactional` to the method of the service or bean where the fetching and getUsers() access is being done. Make sure Transactions are turned on with `@EnableTransactionManagement`.

Comment: If I don't use the `@JaversSpringDataAuditable` annotation on my repository, everything works fine. But as soon as I add that, it starts breaking. So I think Javers is using it somewhere for auditing the author of the change performed.